# Ionic How to implement pressing,release,drag,drop event of button?

Tags: angular, typescript, button, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop

I am implementing recording feature that can record while pressing a button, stop when release.
So I used ionic-long-press plugin.
But I notice that it can't treat the drag and drop event.
Any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/wbhob/ionic-long-press
https://github.com/AbineshSrishti/ionic2-selection-card-drag
I solved the problem using these plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately drag/drop events are not supported on mobile devices but they supports touch events.

So either you can use touch ( `touchstart/touhend/touchmove`) events or if you want to use HTML 5 `drag/drop` events on mobile devices then you will have to include following [drag-drop-touch polyfill](https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch/blob/master/DragDropTouch.js) in your project.

This polyfill does the magic and maps touch events to drag / drop events. I have tried this in my project and it works like charm.